Node.js mTLS authentication using Windows Certificate Store
Normally for mTLS HTTP requests in Node.js, you do the following:
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const req = https.request(
  {
    hostname: 'server.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('client.key'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('server-ca.crt')
  },
  res => {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      // Process response...
    });
  }
);

req.end();

Is there a way to auto-populate the client certificate/key (client.crt and client.key) from the Windows Certificate Store without having to explicitly access them and pass them to this API (using some low level Windows API). This can especially be useful when the certificate key is not exportable.

Accessing the private key data of a Windows cert store entry is equivalent to exporting it. Therefore non-exportable entries will never work this way. And exportable would always trigger the export dialog. Consider Windows cert store as an HSM - and a HSM always require to not only use the private key but completely externalize the crypto operations into the HSM. Only this way this will work. Therefore you would require a https implementation that allows pluggable crypto modules in a language where you can access the native Windows cert store API.
